# Assumptions in Integrate not working properly

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I have the following code:

```
s[x_, y_] = (((n*\[Pi])/b*Cos[(m*\[Pi]*x)/a]*
     Sin[(n*\[Pi]*y)/b])^2 + ((m*\[Pi])/a*Sin[(m*\[Pi]*x)/a]*
     Cos[(n*\[Pi]*y)/b])^2)

Integrate[s[x, y], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, 
 Assumptions -> m \[Element] Integers && n \[Element] Integers]
```

Which outputs

```
(b m \[Pi] (2 m \[Pi] - Sin[2 m \[Pi]]))/(8 a) + (
 a n^2 \[Pi] (2 m \[Pi] + Sin[2 m \[Pi]]))/(8 b m)
```

It's rather trivial, I know, but I cannot seem to get rid of the sin terms and am very curious to know why that is. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I've seen this before.

I normally do the simplification on the result from `Integrate`

```
Assuming[Element[{m, n}, Integers], Integrate[s[x, y], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think Integrate does not see, or "overlooks" the assumptions sometimes. May be it depends on code path taken or at what stage `Integrate` should apply the assumptions. I can see this getting complicated for `Integrate`.

Compare to

```
Integrate[s[x, y], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, Assumptions -> Element[{m, n}, Integers]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

btw, `DSolve` is also known to "sometimes" ignore assumptions.

Comment: With v12.1.0 I get the simpler result when using `Assuming` even without the `Simplify`.

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks. Sure, I did not check, I just normally throw in `Simplify` all the time. But I just removed it since not needed in this case.